# How to lessen the space created by "white-space: pre-line". Below is the picture i applied pre-line property to

Tags: html, css

```
   <div class="right">
        <div class="set-left" ><p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +92 313 2724258</p></div>

        <div class="set-mid" >
          <a href="#" style="padding: 8px;"><i class="fa fa-comments " style="margin-right: 5px;"></i> Live Chat</a>
          <a href="login.html" style="padding: 8px"><i class="fa fa-user" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i> Login</a>
          <a href="register.html" style="padding: 8px"><i class="fa fa-user" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i> Register</a>
        </div>

        <div class="set-right" >
            <a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-facebook" ></i></a>
            <a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-twitter" ></i></a>
            <a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-google-plus" ></i></a>
            <a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-linkedin" ></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I used white-space: pre-line in styles to centrally align these divs but i want to lessen the space between them

Comment: I don't see anywhere `white-space:pre-line` is being used.

Comment: Thankyou for your response @King11, i used it in styles but i got the solution by using line height. Sorry incomplete question as it was my first here.